# jQuery Plugin - DIV boxes changer/fader?

Tags: css, jquery-plugins, jquery

Could you help me out with a link or two to a plugin that automatically fades through different div boxes. Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <img src="test1.jpg" />
    <p>text1</p>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <img src="test2.jpg" />
    <p>text2</p>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <img src="test3.jpg" />
    <p>text3</p>
</div>
```

Thank you. All input appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wish to fade them in in order?

```
$(".box:first").fadeIn("fast", f=function(){
    if($(this).next(".box").length != 0) $(this).next(".box").fadeIn("fast", f);
});
```

**EDIT**

Make sure the boxes are hidden by default:

CSS: `.box { display: none; }` or jQuery: `$(".box").hide()`.

Comment: Thanks man! Unfortunately it doesn't work. I've set up a [test page](http://test.sopranowebdesign.com/boxes.html) if you wanna take a quick look. All the best, Cris.

Comment: Actually it does work, I just forgot you need to set your boxes are hidden by default. Edited my answer.

Comment: Yeah, now it works :) I didn't express myself right... I want only one box to be visible at a time (like a slideshow only with fadeIn effect)... should I set the other non-active boxes hidden?

Comment: Yes, like with buttons (only I don't need the buttons). It just needs to be a continuous loop.

Comment: You are welcome. :) I'd appreciate it if you +1 my helpful comment...? :D

Answer (score 1):

Maybe http://www.webanddesigners.com/15-jquery-slideshow-and-plugins